# Diameter of the Cayley graph of $\mathbb{Z}_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, graph-theory, cayley-graphs

So, I have $G = \mathbb{Z}_n$ and $T_n = \{g\in\mathbb{Z}_n: \operatorname{gcd}(g,n) = 1\} = \mathbb{Z}_n^*$.
I need to find the diameter of $\Gamma(G,T_n)$.

What have I tried: we can obviously try to find the longest distance from $0$-vertex, and there are $\varphi(n)$ vertexes that connected to it, let it be that we go to $x$-vertex, than we need to find what (from $T_n$) we can add to $x$ the way that sum won't be from $T_n$.

And than I lost... I tried some ways how to do it, including to somehow use the CRT, but I think that there's no need to use something this powerful to solve this, and I have a feeling that I missing something very simple there...

The most productive idea for me was to factorize $T_n$ by prime numbers in decomposition of $|G|$ and I believe that answer is connected to it, but...

Comment: I, too, am interested in the diameter of Cayley graphs; what is the motivation behind this particular question? It could be relevant to what I'm working on . . .

Comment: Wouldn't the Cayley graph here be just a cycle of length $n$? Not that I am a specialist... Edit: i.e. might you have misinterpreted the question and taken $T_n$ to be the set of **all** elements with the GCD condition instead of a specific one?

Comment: In this context, what is $\Gamma$ defined as?

Comment: @Amateur_Algebraist
I think it is properly, $T$ is the set of invertible elements of the ring $\mathbb{Z}_n$. If $T$ consisted of one element (or rather two), the problem would be trivial.

Comment: In that case, won't the $0$-vertex be isolated? I'm using the definition from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_graph.

Comment: Your notation is unclear. What exactly does your notation $\mathbb Z^+_n$ represent? It is *not* a standard notation. I **might** have guessed that $\mathbb Z_n$ represents the cyclic group of order $n$ under the operation of modular addition, represented by the integers $\{0,...,n-1\}$. But that plus sign is not standard.

Comment: Sorry for didn't answering for too long: so, Shaun, I am just doing a research on Cayley graphs at my university; about notation: @kabenyuk have written exactly the notation I was using, and thank you very much, how can I see, you've solved the problem (except that conditions about $\varphi(n)$, I'll try to fix that without that theorem you send if I can)... so, thank you and all once more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an answer to the question,
but some clarifications that will perhaps remove the issues noted in the comments.
However, I will give some partial results here.
The question is very interesting in my opinion,
so it's probably already been solved somewhere.
But I couldn't find the reference.

First a few notations.
The set of integers modulo $n$ with the operations of addition and multiplication is a ring.
I denote it by $\mathbb{Z}_n$.
The additive group of this ring I denote by the same symbol $\mathbb{Z}_n$.
The multiplicative group of integers modulo $n$,
which is the group of units in this ring, may be written as $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$
The order of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is $n$ and the order of $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$ is the number of integers in
$\{0,1,\dots ,n-1\}$ coprime to $n$.
It is given by Euler's totient function: $|\mathbb{Z}_n^*|=\varphi(n)$

Consider a Cayley graph $\Gamma_n=\operatorname{Cay}(\mathbb{Z}_n,T)$,
where $T$ can be defined as $T=\mathbb{Z}_n^*$.
Recall that two vertices $x$ and $y$ of $\Gamma_n$ are adjacent if $y=x+t$ for some $t\in T$.
The graph $\Gamma_n$ has no loops (since $0\not\in T$),
is undirected (since $-T=T$),
and is connected (since $\mathbb{Z}_n=\langle T\rangle$).
The degree of each vertex of $\Gamma_n$ is $\varphi(n)$.

Now about the diameter of the graph $\Gamma_n$ ($\operatorname{diam}\Gamma_n$).

It is clear, that $\operatorname{diam}\Gamma_1=0$.

> **Lemma 1.** If $n$ is prime, then $\operatorname{diam}\Gamma_n=1$.  The converse is also true, if $\Gamma_n$ is a graph of diameter $1$,
> then $n$ is prime.

*The proof* is obvious.

The following observations will be useful in the future.
If $T\cup(T+T)=\mathbb{Z}_n$, then $\operatorname{diam}\Gamma_n\leq2$.
If $T\cup(T+T)\cup(T+T+T)=\mathbb{Z}_n$, then $\operatorname{diam}\Gamma_n\leq3$.
In both cases the converse is also true.

Well indeed, for example in the first statement if the distance from $0$ to $x$ is $2$,
then it follows from the definition of the Cayley graph $\Gamma_n$ that $x\in T+T$ and vice versa.

> **Lemma 2.**  If $n$ is odd and not prime and $\dfrac{n}{\varphi(n)}<3$, then $\operatorname{diam}\Gamma_n=2$.

*Proof.* It is obvious that $\operatorname{diam}\Gamma_n\geq2$.
Suppose that $\operatorname{diam}\Gamma_n\geq3$.
This means that there exists $x\in\mathbb{Z}_n$ such that $x\not\in T$ and $x\not\in T+T$.
Hence, since $x$ is odd, it follows
$$
x+T\cap T=\varnothing,
2x+T\cap T=\varnothing, \text{ and }
x+T\cap 2x+T=\varnothing.
$$
We therefore have $T\cup (x+T)\cup(2x+T)\subset\mathbb{Z}_n$ and
$$
n\geq|T\cup (x+T)\cup(2x+T)|=|T|+|x+T|+|2x+T|=3\varphi(n),
$$
i.e. $n/\varphi(n)\geq3$.
The contradiction proving our lemma.

Note that if $n$ is an odd number less than $10^7$, then $n/\varphi(n)<3$.

> **Lemma 3.** If $n>2$ is even but not a power of two and  $\dfrac{n}{\varphi(n)}<4$, then $\operatorname{diam}\Gamma_n=3$.

*Proof.*
Let us first consider the case $n=2m$ with odd $m$.
In this case, every element of $T$ is odd, hence $m\not\in T+T$ (since $m$ divides $n$, $m\not\in T$) and consequently
$\operatorname{diam}\Gamma_n\geq3$.

To prove that $\operatorname{diam}\Gamma_n<4$ it is enough to check that $(T+T)\cup(T+T+T)=\mathbb{Z}_n$.
First prove that $T+T=2\mathbb{Z}_n$.
If $x\in2\mathbb{Z}_n$ and $x\not\in T+T$, then
$$
x+T\cap T=\varnothing,
$$
and
$$
2\mathbb{Z}_n\supset x+T\cup T.
$$
We have
$$
m\geq |x+T\cup T|=2\varphi(n)\Rightarrow\ n/\varphi(n)\geq4.
$$
Contradiction.

Now since $|\mathbb{Z}_n:2\mathbb{Z}_n|=2$ we obtain
$$
(T+T)\cup(T+T+T)=2\mathbb{Z}_n\cup(T+T)+T=2\mathbb{Z}_n\cup(2\mathbb{Z}_n+1)=\mathbb{Z}_n.
$$

The case $n=2^km$ with odd $m$ and $k>1$
is simpler than the considered case and I omit it.

> **Lemma 4.** If $n>2$ is a power of two, then $\operatorname{diam}\Gamma_n=2$.

*Proof.*
In this case $T$ consists exactly of all odd elements of $\mathbb{Z}_n$, i.e. $T=2\mathbb{Z}_n+1$ hence
$T+T=2\mathbb{Z}_n$. It follows $\operatorname{diam}\Gamma_n=2$.

**PS.1** It is possible that in general it is always $\operatorname{diam}\Gamma_n\leq3$.

**PS.2** I did find [a reference](https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v14i1r45/pdf) Theorem 9.